# Programmatically Create Site Collection within a Specific Content DB or move to a specific Content DB using SP Object Model & Not PowerShell

Tags: site-collection, content-database, object-model, move, ssom

Is it possible to specify the Content DB to which a site collection will belong while creating a Site Collection? I am using the SelfServiceCreateSite API. If not, is there a way to move a site collection to a specific Content DB? Can anyone please provide the code? I know both these requirements are possible in PowerShell. But I need to achieve it using Object Model.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms411953.aspx) using SSOM.

```
SPWebApplication webApp = new SPSite("http://MySiteCollection").WebApplication;
SPSiteCollection siteCollections = webApp.Sites;

SPSite newSiteCollection = siteCollections.Add("sites/Site_Name", 
    "Site_Title", "Site_Description", 1033, "STS#0", 
    "DOMAIN\\Owner", "Owner_Display_Name", 
    "Owner_Email", "DOMAIN\\Contact", 
    "Contact_Display_Name", "Contact_Email",
    "Database_Server", "Database_Name", null, null);
```

More info in [SPSiteCollection.Add method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsitecollection.add.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

**PowerShell** is just a wrapper for the object model.

You can create Web Template & create Sites and Site Collections from that Custom Web Template using method mentioned in below reference.

[Programmatically creating Sites and Site Collections from a Custom Web Template](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-creating-sites-site-collections-custom-web-template/)

> ---------------------EXAMPLE 1-----------------------
>
> ```
> Move-SPSite http://servername/sites/sitename -DestinationDatabase ContentDb2
> ```
>
> This example moves the site collection
>   http://servername/sites/sitename to the content database ContentDb2.
>
> ---------------------EXAMPLE 2-----------------------
>
> ```
> Get-SPSite -ContentDatabase ContentDb1 | Move-SPSite -DestinationDatabase ContentDb2
> ```
>
> This example moves all site collections in ContentDb1 to ContentDb2.
>
> ---------------------EXAMPLE 3-----------------------
>
> ```
> Get-SPSiteAdministration | where { $_.OwnerLoginName -eq "DOMAIN\username" } | Move-SPSite -DestinationDatabase ContentDb2
> ```
>
> This example moves all site collections where DOMAIN\username is the
>   site collection owner to ContentDb2. The **Get-SPSiteAdministration**
>   cmdlet is used instead of the **Get-SPSite** cmdlet because you must
>   have permission within the site collection to access the properties of
>   the SPSite object. You can access the properties of the
>   **SPSiteAdministration** object as a SharePoint farm administrator.
>
> ---------------------EXAMPLE 4-----------------------
>
> ```
> Move-SPSite -Identity siteUrl -DestinationDatabase databaseName -RbsProviderMapping       @{"sourceProvider1"="targetProvider1", "sourceProvider2"="targetProvider2"}
> ```
>
> This example moves an RBS-enabled site collection from one RBS-enabled
>   content database to another RBS-enabled content database,
>   **sourceProvider1** is the source RBS provider and **targetProvider1** is the target RBS provider.

Comment: Have you tried it? Is this works for you?